# How to continue controller execution after load->view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form to add new product. When product is added I need to write notifications in database for users that would be interested in this product. What I want to do is to display  success message and continue with saving notifications.

In plain php we would use combination of `ob_start()`, `ob_end_flush()` and `ignore_user_abort()` however I can not get to understand how to get this working in CodeIgniter.

Here is simple example:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()){
    $this->load->view('success', $data);
    $x = 1; 
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.txt';
    $file = fopen($path,"w");
    while($x <= 5) {
        echo fwrite($file,"new product".$x);
        $x++;
        sleep(5);
    } 
    fclose($file);
}
```

Thing is that I do not completelly understand how CI loads view files. In given example I have to wait 25 second (5*5) until view is loaded. So the question have to parts:

1. How to force loading view immediately?
2. How to set ignore_user_aborts() in CI?

Comment: Hi. Use ajax... But why you write data to file? I don't undrestand you thinking...

Comment: It is just an example to understand how everything work. I am currently using ajax. I triger ajax call if product is succesfully added. However I have to manipulate to image of product and response can take 1-2 seconds. If user exits browser the ajax is not trigered